# Get Android Emulator To Display/Render On A Dedicated Display

Tags: screen, android-emulator

I have a phone sized external HDMI touch screen display.
Instead of the android emulator in a window on the desktop. I want to be able to display directly to that touch screen display.
A quick look through the emulator docs got me able to pass through the GPU directly to the android emulator but that still displays the "screen" of the emulated phone in a window on the desktop.
A Glance at qemu2 docs didn't reveal anything more.

Comment: Additional info/details about your PC's OS (Windows/Mac/Linux) (graphics system / GPU driver) setup and emulator commands you are using to display to the second screen may be helpful.